# Will Spark create a s3 folder path if it doesn't exist?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

Let's say I have this line, I want to know if Spark automatically creates a folder path and writes to folder like it does in local.

Yes, s3 is not folder system rather a key val system.

```
val path="s3a://dev-us-east-1/"

val op = df_formatted.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").save(path + "report/output")
```

Will this be written to "s3a://dev-us-east-1/report/output"

Comment: I am not sure with the S3 but have tested in Azure blob storage, It creates a folder as it does in local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Granted that you have set correctly the "security stuff", that is that you have credentials of an IAM user with write access, then yes Spark will create folders and files.